# modify a javascript code using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

well i have this javascript code :

```
<div id="change">
   <script>
      var change=0;
   </script>     
</div>
```

and I use ajax to update it. In fact when I update my database I want to alter the variable 'change' to the value 1.:

```
function update(value,username,competency)
{

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
         document.getElementById("updateAll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
         document.getElementById("change").innerHTML='<script >var change=1</script> '; 
      }
   };
   xmlhttp.open("GET","Update_evaluation_ajax.php?value="+value+"&username="+username+"&competency="+competency,true);
   xmlhttp.send(null); 
}
```

Can you help me figure out why this does not work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [setting innerHTML with a script inside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694977/setting-innerhtml-with-a-script-inside)

Comment: i have tried document.getElementsByTagName("script")[4].innerHTML='var change=1 ';

Comment: var script = document.createElement('script');
    script[(script.innerText===undefined?"textContent":"innerText")] = 'change =1;';
    document.body.appendChild(script); does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<script>` tags added with `innerHTML` are NOT executed.

Why not just set `change = 1` instead of setting the `innerHTML`? It looks like `change` is a global variable, so you can change it from anywhere.

Comment: yes tried change=1 and window.change=1 and document.change=1 .

Comment: if(change==1)
    {
  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var e = e || window.event;

  //IE & Firefox
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Are you sure?';
  }

  // For Safari
  return 'Are you sure?';
};
} this fragment of code it is not executed that why i know it's not working.

Comment: If you've already run the code, it's not going to run again just because a variable changes. You have to call it again. Or, put the `if change == 1` bit inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

When your initial `<script>` tag is executed, it creates a global variable `change` that can be accessed via `window.change`.

Presumably you're expecting to use the `change` variable elsewhere in your code. Without seeing that code it's difficult to suggest a good solution, but you can simply set `window.change` inside you response function and any subsequent code that's executed will use the updated value (depending on scope):

```
function () {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
  {
     document.getElementById("updateAll").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; 
     window.change = 1;
  }
};
```

Of course global variables are bad, but that's outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: ok i did find the problem : i was doing that if(change==1)
    {
  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var e = e || window.event;

  //IE & Firefox
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Are you sure?';
  }

  // For Safari
  return 'Are you sure?';
};
}  but i had to do that :  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {if(change==1)
    {
 
  var e = e || window.event;

  //IE & Firefox
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Are you sure?';
  }

  // For Safari
  return 'Are you sure?';
};
}