# Return Jquery UI Slider From AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, jquery-ui-slider

I have two pages first one is ask.jsp and second one is get.jsp.On ask .jsp there is a button...which is when pressed get.jsp is called through ajax and i am trying to return a slider from that page ...but not able to see it ...but if i send some text message from that page it is displayed on ask.jso so how can i return a slider through second page?
**ask.jsp**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1256"
        pageEncoding="windows-1256"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
    <script>
    function update()
    {

        var xmlhttp;    

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
$( "#slider" ).slider();
            document.getElementById("refresh").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","get.jsp");
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="button" id="1" value="1" onClick="update();"/>

    <%
    int value=1;
    %>
    <div id="refresh">
    <%=value %>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**get.jsp**

```
$(function() {
$( "#slider" ).slider();
});
</script>
<p>
heyyyyyyyyyy
</p>
<p id="slider">
</p>
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QJAsaM8KvlTrfRpsUUMl?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reorganize get.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<p>
    heyyyyyyyyyy
</p>
<p id="slider">
</p>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider" ).slider();
    });
</script>
```

move the script to the bottom

Also use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load the remote html to a element

```
function update(){
    $('#refresh').load('get.jsp')
}
```

It looks like the problem is the script elements inserted via `innerHTML` [will not get executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694977/setting-innerhtml-with-a-script-inside)

Comment: because it seems to be working fine http://plnkr.co/edit/GqunD04ty4HqxY7m6kab?p=preview

Comment: Add an `alert($( "#slider" ).length)` before `$( "#slider" ).slider();` and see what is happening

Comment: why can't you load jquery and jquery-ui related script in the main file (ask.jsp) instead of get.jsp

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27961/discussion-between-james-and-arun-p-johny)

Comment: @james I was able to recreate the issue in the following demo http://plnkr.co/edit/umbhpk0imOg4JAGSIs4n?p=preview

Comment: @james and the issue is fixed in http://plnkr.co/edit/9Pisxz0QurNqECvEWNOX?p=preview by using jquery to load the remote content as given in my answer `function update()
{
    
    $('#refresh').load('get.jsp')
    
}`

Comment: i am displaying slider on the basis of user input..how do i dynamically bind sliders here..id will be given in loop.

Comment: @james yes, i think instead of using `id` use a class attribute, and assign the same class to all sliders like `<p class="my-slider"></p>` then `$( ".my-slider" ).slider();`

Comment: @james check the above one and let me know

Comment: it worked but i want to uniquely identify each slider. how could i achieve this?

Comment: @james then you need to create a dynamic id like using a loop index

Comment: could you provide any demo?

Comment: for(i=0;i<5;i++)$(function() {
$( "#slider<%=i%>" ).slider();
});
</script>
<p>
heyyyyyyyyyy
</p>
<p id="slider%=i%">
</p>}

Comment: How to create a dynamic id?

Answer (score 1):

In your success function inside your AJAX call, re-call the function responsabile of displaying the slider.

I don't use AJAX the way you do in your code, but certainly, there is a success function there

(maybe your success part  is :

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)) {}
```

)

Note: As I know, AJAX is better by using the jquery ajax function like:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "url.php",
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: ({ action: 'youraction', parameters... }),
                    success: function(data){

                          $( "#slider" ).slider(); 
                          // other AJAX actions.
                    },
                    error: function(data)  
                    {  

                    }  


                });
```

Good luck.

Comment: function that is responsible for displaying slider or that div?                                                                    <script>
$(function() {
$( "#slider" ).slider();
});
</script>                                                           this is the function of jquery ui slider and                                                                 <p id="slider">
</p>                                                                 this shows slider

Comment: but where is your success part of your AJAX call??? I never used xmlhttp, check my edit to know how can I add your function in my success part

Comment: I hope I am clear. In the way you are using AJAX, there is certainly a place where do you put your functions where the AJAX call succeddd. In this place, call $( "#slider" ).slider();

Comment: tell me, what is your success part of your AJAX call??

Comment: if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("refresh").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }

Comment: you can see this part in start of ask.jsp

Comment: yes I see it, now I am editing my answer so that it englobes all what I think. give me two minutes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27962/discussion-between-james-and-letters-and-blank-spaces)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should:

- 1 remove all your link tags and script tags from get.jsp. Keep only
  necessary HTML tags (in your case : `<p id="slider"></p>`). Our of course you should call these libraries in your main page.
- 2 In your AJAX call, after the AJAX finished returning the required
  staf, re-call again the jquery action responsable of displaying the
  slider

  in your case, this action is `$( "#slider" ).slider();`. so call it
  inside of `if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)` or maybe
  after `xmlhttp.send();`. The idea here is to re-call it so that you
  trigger it after the DOM is updated by AJAX.
- 3 If all these solutions dont work, use the jquery new ajax way like
  described in my first answer.

Comment: where should i put link tags and script tags?

Comment: ok i just saw that it shows for few miliseconds and disappears

Comment: slider below hey if you keep on clickinh that 1 button it show up for a few mili seconds ..

Comment: nice then. but tell us now what is your progress by editing your code.

Comment: when i remove the script tag slider just came for a while and gone.